# How do I add the login form in page.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8, users

I am using a subtheme from the [Neato](https://www.drupal.org/project/neato) theme (in Drupal 8) and I am customizing page.html.twig.

Yesterday I performed a logout, and now I want to log in again, but the login form has disappeared.

How do I add the login form in page.html.twig? Do I need another html.twig file?

Comment: The page.html.twig (usually) prints the layouts (configured by the theme). the user login block is placed (in normal installations) in the sidebar region. You should post your current page.html.twig file for better support.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to go directly to the path '/user' where the login form will be the main contents of the page.

Comment: That's the answer to the question you are apparently actually asking. Once you did that, you can place a login form block, there should also be a login link by default somewhere. Unless you "customized" your page.html.twig so much/badly that your main content is gone. Then you best rename it so you get the normal content again.